# mysql get latest records by order by desc without subquery

Tags: mysql, sql

Im trying to get result with below query but its taking around 2min to retrieve

```
SELECT * 
FROM customer e 
WHERE e.id=324 
AND e.g_id IN('x133fv','be6544','e992170','93611c') 
and e.enrol_id = 
(
 select e1.enrol_id 
 from customer e1 
 WHERE e1.id=324 
 AND e1.g_id=e.g_id 
 ORDER BY update_time DESC, posted_time DESC, enrol_id DESC 
 LIMIT 1
)
```

I have index on (g_id,id)

Is there any other way to get the result via JOIN?

Comment: I'm with Gordon on this. Don't look for another way. This query looks good and reads well. If it takes too long, then you should look at the EXPLAIN plan and try to see if it can be made efficient by adding an index. Since you have 2 equality conditions on id and g_id and an order by on another 3 columns, Gordon's suggestion of adding a composite 5 column index may very well solve your problems.

Comment: Frazz, gordon index just helped me gain 6 seconds from total 2min output time. :(

Answer (score 1):

This is your query:

```
SELECT *
FROM customer e
WHERE e.id = 324 AND
      e.g_id IN ('x133fv','be6544','e992170','93611c') and
      e.enrol_id = (select e1.enrol_id
                    from customer e1
                    WHERE e1.id=324 AND e1.g_id=e.g_id
                    ORDER BY update_time DESC, posted_time DESC, enrol_id DESC
                    LIMIT 1
                   )
```

You can improve the performance with indexes.  I would suggest: `customer(id, g_id, update_time, posted_time, enrol_id)`.

Comment: Thanks for the response... But is it possible to get a JOIN rather than subquery?

Comment: I added this index but still its using the old index (g_id,id). Did analyze table several times also and did FORCE INDEX too but still took same time..

Comment: @user3752021 . . . As I look at the query, only one index is necessary.

Comment: The new index of customer(id, g_id, update_time, posted_time, enrol_id) helped to gain only 6seconds from original 2min output time. :(  any other option  to reduce the time.

Comment: @user3752021 . . . Try making that:  `customer(g_id, id, update_time, posted_time, enrol_id)`

Comment: I did try that option but same 6second gain.

Comment: @user3752021 . . . If you replace the `in` with a comparison to just one value, does the performance improve dramatically?

Comment: Bascially if i just have 1 group ID and if I remove subquery Link from e1.g_id=e.g_id to e1.g_id IN (1groupid). This performs the best. But i cant do that since i have multi groupid in play. Thats why i was asking if rewrite JOIN can help here.

Comment: Try moving the "g_id IN(...)" condition into the SUBSELECT... or replicating it (like you did the "id =" condition). Just to see if this works better with the index.